# How to structure and query firestore data of all group messages for particular user in a whatsapp like app?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

### Story

My app is not a chat app but my use case is very similar to that. Imagine a group chat app like whatsapp where people added in the group can see messages of that group.

**Scenario**

1. Groups will have participants
2. Groups will have messages

**Requirement**

1. When user opens the app, I want every group where he is participant to be synced in his device.

### Data Modelling Case 1: Participants array at group level

```js
firestoreRoot: {
   groupsCollection : {
      group1Id: {
        participantsArray: ['user1','user2'],
        messagesSubCollection : {msg1:{...data},msg2:{...data},msg3:{...data},...{...}}
      }
   }
}
```

**How to get all messages?**

1. For this do I need to query group first where is the participants. Then I need to query again for all groups messages? Is that right? If he is part of 50 groups then 50 new queries will be made.
2. Will collection queries help? Can i query all messages from parent data like `message.parent.participants hasElement clientUserId`. Can i access parent field in sub collection data? Then i can do single query but not sure this feature is there?

### Data Modelling Case 2: Participants array in all messages

```js
firestoreRoot: {
   groupsCollection : {
      group1Id: {
        messagesSubCollection : 
            [
            msg1:{...data,participantArray:['user1','user2']},
            msg2:{...data,participantArray:['user1','user2']},
            msg3:{...data,participantArray:['user1','user2']},
            ]
      }
   }
}
```

**How to get all messages?**

1. I will create collection group index of `messageSubCollection`. I will query all messages where `participantArray hasElement clientUserId`. Only single query will work.
2. But now I have to repeat participant array in all messages? If there are 100 participants, then this huge data will be repeated. If user add or remove one participant then all the messages in that group needs to be updated.

### Help

1. Can i go with anyone of these scenario depending upon simplicity/cost based on my use cases?
2. Am i missing some another feature?

Comment: Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: Which case are you talking about?

Comment: With one and the other.

Comment: In case 1, I have to query groups first,  then query again for all sub collection say 50 times for each group. In case 2, I have to update all messages in group when any participant is changed, say 100-1000 messages for a group? Is this the normal way or I am missing something?

Comment: In the NoSQL world, we are usually structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. So if you can query those schemas and return the desired documents, then why not go ahead with it?